# Document Center Search is not working in Mathematica 11.3?

Tags: front-end, warning-messages

If I type "Table" (without the quotes, of course) or any other search term into the Documentation Center search, I get:

```
Your search -Table- in Documentation Center did not find any documents.
```

If I drill-down from the documentation center front page, I will eventually find the help page for Table (and other search terms).  So the documents are there, but the Document Center Search and F1 for the highlighted function do not work.

Is there a workaround or download that can be applied to make this work?

Comment: Does typing in `ref/Table` take you to the page? What if you delete your config files? http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Comment: I'm seeing the following messages "TextSearch: An internal error occurred while performing the search. Please contact technical support".

Comment: JLink/Java: Method named searchTagged defined in class com.wolfram.textsearch.TextSearchIndex was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments."  The arguments shown here in the list were (CreateUUID[],TextSearch`PackageScope`qUnion[TextSearch`PackageScope`qString[NormalizedTitle,table],1000], TextSearch`PackageScope`qString[All,Table]],{}].

Comment: Did you contact technical support...? Have you deleted the directories in the article I mentioned? Have you uninstalled/reinstalled?

Comment: Deleted the directories as per kb/12464.  This solved the issue.

Comment: Could you put this solution as a reply (instead of a comment) and I will check it as the solution.